# JavaScript document innerHTML is not getting the text

Tags: javascript, html, text

So I have a value that is being written when the page is loaded using JavaScript. I want to get that value for use, so I perform a document.getElementById("").innerHTML from a second JS file. **My problem is that the value is not being grabbed.**

I did a check by adding a word after grabbing the value (This is all done in the second JS file). After refreshing the page, only the word is shown, instead of the expected value + word.

Also, the word is only shown for a moment, then it is overwritten by the value. I'm suspecting that somehow the second JS file is being loaded first before the first JS file, and since the first JS file is loaded after, the value has not yet been written, therefore the second JS file could not grab it.

I'm not sure if my suspicion is accurate, but if it is, is there any way for me to solve this? If not, what is the issue I'm experiencing here?

Here's the body of my html file where the value is written:

```
<body onload="update()">
  <div id="height"></div>
  <ul class="board list-group" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div id="lb"></div>
  </ul>
</body>  
</html>
```

Here's a part of my first JS file where I'm writing the value that I want to get:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      resultString = xmlhttp.responseText;
      arrayInfo = resultString.split(";");
      document.getElementById("height").innerHTML = arrayInfo.length;
    }
};
```

Here's the part in my second JS file where I'm trying to grab that value:

```
max = 1000; 
temp = document.getElementById("height").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("height").innerHTML += temp + "test";
offset = min = 0;  
pressed = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first JS file you seem to be using an Ajax call which usually takes some time to complete. The second script will be called regardless whether the success function of your first file completed.

To be on the safe side you should fire the Ajax call only after the page - including your second js script - was loaded (-> pack it into function `update()`). In your your second JS file you should then encapsulate the desired action into another function (`update2()`). This function should then be called from within the success function of your first JS file.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I know, this is unsolicited advice, but maybe you should be looking into using jQuery. It *does* make Ajax and DOM manipulation so much easier. ;-)

Comment: Does it really? I just started and JavaScript looks less intimidating to learn, so that's why I have not looked at jQuery yet. But I will look into that, thank you for the suggestion.

And also, your solution works great, thank you so much.